# Extraction of sublists containing certain sequence pairs

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

```
 list =
  {{a, b, c, d, a},
   {e, f, a, b, c, d},
   {a, b, p, q, c, d, g, h},
   {c, d, p, q, a, b},
   {a, c, b, d}};
```

I want to filter sublists of `list` based upon two conditions:

(1) sublist must contain (a, b) AND (c, d)

```
y = {a, b} | {c, d};
```

(2) AND sublist must NOT contain (e, f) OR (g, h)

```
n = {e, f} | {g, h};
```

Duplicated pairs within a sublist like `{a,b,c,d,a,b}` don't occur.

I came up with the following solution:

```
Extract[#, Position[SequenceCases[#, y] & /@ #, {_, _}, 1]]& @
 Delete[list, Position[SequenceCases[#, n] & /@ list, {{_, _}}, 1]]
```

{{a, b, c, d, a}, {c, d, p, q, a, b}}

I am, of course, not happy with the serial `Extract` / `Delete`.
Which alternative solutions would you suggest?

Comment: Why is  `{a,b,c,d}` i.e., the last entry not part of the desired answer? It has `{a,b,c,d}` and none of `{e,f,g,h}`. **Never mind** you are talking about sequence pairs. Sorry about that.

Comment: The last entry is `{a, c, b, d}` and not `{a, b, c, d}` as you suggest. The latter would qualify, the first not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list = {{a, b, c, d, a}, {e, f, a, b, c, d}, {a, b, p, q, c, d, g, 
    h}, {c, d, p, q, a, b}, {a, c, b, d}};

delpatt = {a, Except[b]} | {c, Except[d]} | {e, f} | {g, h};
```

The idea is to mark any unwanted pattern as "X" and then delete any sublists containing "X".

```
SequenceReplace[#, delpatt :> "X" ] & /@ list // 
 DeleteCases[_?(ContainsAny[{"X"}])]
```

> {{a, b, c, d, a}, {c, d, p, q, a, b}}

Comment: Slightly shorter: `// Select[FreeQ @ "X"]`

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the accept. `SequenceReplace` can take an additional argument which is the number of replacements. To be discarded, the sublist needs to have one "X" only. This option may become useful if sublists have a longer length.

Answer (score 5):

```
selectBySequenceCounts[seqs_List, counts_List] := 
 Select[$x |-> counts == Map[SequenceCount[$x, #] &]@seqs]
```

***Examples:***

```
y = {a, b} | {c, d};

n = {e, f} | {g, h};

list = {{a, b, c, d, a}, 
        {e, f, a, b, c, d}, 
        {a, b, p, q, c, d, g, h},   
        {c, d, p, q, a, b},
        {a, c, b, d}, 
        {a, b, c, d, a, b}};

selectBySequenceCounts[{## & @@ y, n}, {1, 1, 0}] @ list
```

> ```
>  {{a, b, c, d, a}, {c, d, p, q, a, b}}
> ```

***"Duplicated pairs within a sublist like {a,b,c,d,a,b} don't occur."***

```
list2 = {{a, b, c, d, a, b}};

selectBySequenceCounts[{## & @@ y, n}, {1, 1, 0}] @ list2
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{a, b, c, d, a}, {e, f, a, b, c, d}, {a, b, p, q, c, d, g, h}, 
        {c, d, p, q, a, b}, {a, c, b, d}};

y = {a, b} | {c, d};

n = {e, f} | {g, h};
```

Using `Select`:

```
test = (FreeQ[#, n] && ! FreeQ[#, y]) &;

part = Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ list;

Function[s, {Splice@s[[All, 1]], s[[-1, 2]]}] /@ Select[part, test]

(*{{a, b, c, d, a}, {c, d, p, q, a, b}}*)
```

Or using `Pick`:

```
Pick[list, test /@ part]

(*{{a, b, c, d, a}, {c, d, p, q, a, b}}*)
```

Another way using `SequenceSplit` and `Pick`:

```
Pick[#, test@Cases[{_, _}]@SequenceSplit[#, s : y :> s] & /@ #] &@list

(*{{a, b, c, d, a}, {c, d, p, q, a, b}}*)
```